# Write a Regex to extract number before '/'

Tags: python, regex

I don't want to use string split because I have numbers 1-99, and a column of string that contain '#/#' somewhere in the text.

How can I write a regex to extract the number 10 in the following example:

```
He got 10/19 questions right.
```

Comment: try \d+(?=\/\d+) [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e4dZdS/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a lookahead to match on the `/`, like this:

```
\d+(?=/)
```

You may need to escape the / if your implementation uses it as its delimiter.

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/xdT4vq/1

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `str.split()` if you carefully construct logic around it:

```
t = "He got 10/19 questions right."
t2 = "He/she got 10/19 questions right"


for q in [t,t2]:


    # split whole string at spaces
    # split each part at / 
    # only keep parts that contain / but not at 1st position and only consists
    # out of numbers elsewise
    numbers = [x.split("/") for x in q.split() 
               if "/" in x and all(c in "0123456789/" for c in x)
              and not x.startswith("/")]
    if numbers:
        print(numbers[0][0])
```

Output:

```
10
10
```

Comment: This assumes that there's no other `/` without numbers. For example, on "He/she got 10/19 questions right.", it will fail.

Comment: @Jos So will yours if you give it `On 05/05/2019 someone will score 9/8 points.` But at least yours will only catch numbers that are followed by `/` . Added some more logic - should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
myString = "He got 10/19 questions right."
oldnumber = re.findall('[0-9]+/', myString)  #find one or more digits followed by a slash.
newNumber = oldnumber[0].replace("/","")  #get rid of the slash.

print(newNumber)
>>>10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = re.search('(\d+)/\d+', r'He got 10/19 questions right.')
res.groups()
('10',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all numbers before the forward-slash and exclude the forward-slash by using start-stop parentheses.

```
>>> import re
>>> myString = 'He got 10/19 questions right.'
>>> stringNumber = re.findall('([0-9]+)/', myString)
>>> stringNumber
['10']
```

This returns all numbers ended with a forward-slash, but in a list of strings. if you want integers, you should `map` your list with `int`, then make a `list` again.

```
>>> intNumber = list(map(int, stringNumber))
>>> intNumber
[10]
```